# $H\lhd G$ implies $C_G(h)/C_H(h)$ is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, normal-subgroups

The actual question is as follows:

Let $G$ be a finite group of odd order, $H$ a subgroup of $G$ of index 3. Let $h\in H$. Prove that $C_H(h) \lhd C_G(h)$ and $C_G(h)/C_H(h)$ is cyclic (where $C_G(h)$ is the centralizer of $h$ in $G$).

Since $H$ is of smallest possible index, we have that $H\lhd G$, and I have shown that $C_H(h) \lhd C_G(h)$ by working through the definitions, but I am unsure how to show the quotient group is cyclic.

Comment: $G/H$ is cyclic, and $C_G(h)/C_H(h)$ a subgroup of it.

Comment: Use the index: Show that under the assumption $[C_G(h):C_H(h)]\le 3$. (If you do not have the index assumption the factor group does not need to be cyclic, take e.g. $G=A_5\times A_5$ and $$H$ one of the direct factors and $h\not=1$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\frac{C_{G}(h)}{C_{H}(h)}
=
\frac{C_{G}(h)}{H \cap C_{G}(h)}
\cong
\frac{H C_{G}(h)}{H},
$$
and the latter is a subgroup of $G/H$.